# I get an error when i build my project in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, build

[![is anyone this how to fix this problem during build? please][1]][1]

when i build my project this error shows up and i dont know how to fix it someone would have a solution
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3SYu.png

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your application with `./gradlew clean build` command to see what's exactly wrong with your code. Just paste it into the Terminal in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the build which bugged due to a version difference between the variant builds

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).